# Getting value from input select Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zf3

how I can get value from input select in ZF3?

```
$education = $form->get('education');
$education->setValueOptions([
     '1' =>'option 1',
     '2' => 'option 2',
]);
```

returns integer value 1,2, not 'option 1' or 'option 2'

Even if I remove index and leave code like below

```
$education->setValueOptions([
     'option 1',
     'option 2',
]);
```

it doesn't work and returns the same as above.

But if I modify code like this

```
$education->setValueOptions([
     'option 1' => 'anything'
     'option 2' => 'anything'
]);
```

it returns correct values as 'option 1' or 'option 2'.

Is is correct, or I'm dooing something wrong?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: yep I just selected your's answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking it wrong. For example:

```
$education->setValueOptions([
     'array_key' => 'array_value'
]);
```

In PHP the value of this array would be `array_value` while `array_key` would be the key. The logic in zend is the opposite when it is translated to the front-end. In the front end the `array_key` would be the `<option>` value while the `array_value` would be the `<option>` label.

The above code would be translated to the following in the front-end

```
<option value="array_key">array_value</option>
```